# How to change font size on a button?

Tags: android, layout, button

I have a button in my Android project that contains two rows with text to the left, and one drawable on the right side. This works perfectly with this code:

```
<Button 
  android:text="Call History" 
  android:id="@+id/accountCallLogButton" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
  android:padding="10sp" 
  android:background="@drawable/buttconfig" 
  android:gravity="left|center_vertical">
 </Button>
```

String resource:

```
<string name="addCreditButtonText">Add Credit\nOpens in browser</string>
```

My problem here is that in the second Line of the String resource, I want to have a smaller font size and italic font.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Put HTML markup in your string resource that describes what you want (italic, smaller font)

Step #2: Use `Html.fromHtml()` to convert that string resource to a `SpannedString`

Step #3: Call `setText()` on your `Button` with that `SpannedString`